# How to trigger JQUERY on Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make a selection box when clicked, the items on the left will shift to right automatically. However, using trigger I cannot achieve this.
Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#assignedSelected').on('click',function(){
        $('#unassignedItems option:selected').clone().appendTo('#assignedItems');       
        $('#unassignedItems option:selected').remove();
    });
    $('#assignedItems').on('click','option', function(){
        $('#assignedSelected').trigger('click');
    });

});

</script>

<table class="selectArea">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="unassignedItems" name="unassignedItems" class="selectBox" size="8" multiple>
                <option value="A">A</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="selectButtonPanel">
            <input type="button" id="assignedSelected" class="selectButton" value="&gt;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="assignedItems" name="assignedItems" class="selectBox" size="8" multiple>
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you share the html? change event is better for select tag.

Comment: try `$('#assignedSelected').click()`

Comment: @Murali That just in turn calls `.trigger('click')`, so won't help.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/tvzBL/ But I don't find any reason for the trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind click on select options, use .change() instead

```
$('#assignedItems').on('change', function(){
    $('#assignedSelected').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I agree it's a better habit to use change rather than click in select options.However, in my case , click event can also be captured by the browser, but I wondered how can I achieve trigger the event by using .on() .

Comment: What do you mean with trigger the event using .on() ?